# Pandas series: select rows int series based upon values from another series

Tags: python, pandas

I have two string series like this

```
>>> a = pd.Series(['a','b','c'])
>>> b = pd.Series(['bb', 'a', 'dd', 'ee'])
>>> a
0    a
1    b
2    c
dtype: object
>>> b
0    bb
1     a
2    dd
3    ee
dtype: object
```

If I want to select all rows in 'a' that match exact rows in 'b' I will use this:

```
>>> a.loc[a.isin(b)]
0    a
dtype: object
```

But how to select all rows/strings in 'a' that is a substring in 'b'? I want to get this:

```
0    a
1    b
```

Comment: This sounds like you want to do a `join` with `type=inner`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the element in `a` is a substring of `b` one by one with `apply` method:

```
a[a.apply(lambda x: b.str.contains(x).any())]

#0    a
#1    b
#dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

You need first create expression with `join` values of `a` with `|` what means `or` in `regex` and then use [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for check values in `b`, last use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filtering:

```
print ('|'.join(a))
a|b|c

print (b.str.contains('|'.join(a)))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool

print (a[b.str.contains('|'.join(a))])
0    a
1    b
dtype: object
```